# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error:Unresolved compilation problems:WebDriver cannot be resolved to atype ChromeDriver cannot be resolved type

Tags: java, selenium

Here is my initial code

```
package NewPackage;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class NewClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Welcome to the Selenium Webdriver");
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\Selenium Jar and drivers\\ChromeDriver\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("www.google.com");
```

I get

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error:Unresolved compilation problems:WebDriver cannot be resolved to atype ChromeDriver cannot be resolved type

Comment: Can you explain it bit more in detail, what you are trying and where you are getting this error.

Comment: Actually i have imported all jar files and class files then i am going to run above code for chrome browser but it shoes error as i mentioned as above one subject                              ultiple markers at this line
 - The import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver cannot be 
  resolved
 - The type org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver is not 
  accessible

Comment: Looks like issue could be in import with IDE, which IDE you are using?